# Custom display dynamic data in WebGrid using MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a WebHelpers WebGrid in MVC 3.0 and would like to custom display a certain field if its value was set to a certain amount.

```
grid1.Column(columnName : "Process_ID",format:@<text>@if (item.Process_ID == 26){<text><SPAN STYLE="background-color: yellow">&nbsp;&nbsp;HELLO&nbsp;&nbsp;</SPAN></text>} </text> ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grid1.Column(columnName : "Process_ID",format:(item.Process_ID == 26)?"<text>Hi</text>":"<text>Bye</text>"}),
```